# Force update of ScaleLine Control in openlayers 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, openlayers

I'm using Openlayers 2 and I'm creating a map app. I'm using apache cordova so it's just javascript/html/css.

It works fine for most cases but when I zoom in and out a bunch of times (with my fingers on a touchscreen) sometimes the scaleline stops updating. Moving the map around and zooming in/out some more usually get's it starting again.

My question is: Is there a way to force the ScaleLine control to redraw (other than moving around the screen and zoom in/out randomly). Like, is there a function I can run on, say, the click of a button to force redrawing?

I've tried

```
map.Control.Scaleline.update();
map.Control.Scaleline.draw();
```

But it doesn't work

Thanks!

PS:
I've tried opening the app from chrome on a desktop and since I don't have the touch screen capability there I can't reproduce the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at OpenLayers.debug.js I could see that scaleline is updated at "moveend" event which is only triggered when touch is completed (which it isn't if the user doesn't let the touch drag finish for example by zooming)

"move" always triggers, so I solved it by triggering "moveend" on "move" event.

```
    map.events.on ({
        "move": function () {
                map.events.triggerEvent("moveend");
            }
        }
    });
```

It removes the detail of adding certain events only on "moveend" but it solves the problem. Please comment if you have a better solution!

Comment: It didn't work for me. It makes drags pan excessively far. Also, the ScaleLine and Graticule still don't get updated. I tested both Control.Navigation and Control.TouchNavigation for the touch input and neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

@atwinther was almost right. The solution is to watch for "touchend" and then send a moveend event. Only the latest browsers support this, however, so it might still be buggy for some people. At the least, according to Mozilla, this should work for the latest Firefox and Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent

This is what I did that worked, with non-essential code ellided:

```
var SYP = {
  init: function() {
    this.map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");

    // workaround for ol2 bug where touch events do not redraw the          
    // graticule or scaleline                                               
    this.map.events.on ({
        "touchend": function () {
            SYP.map.events.triggerEvent("moveend");
        }
    });

  },
```